# Bundle product email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

While searching for the email templates for an order I found this block of the XML file. It clearly specifies which template files are used.
My question is for product type default one can easily find the template file by seeing the addItemRender method and type=default.

But for product type="grouped" the template file that is shown is /email/order/items/order/default.phtml but in actual /bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml is the template file. It will sound silly but any one could let me know why the bundle is not specified in the template path hint, if it is understood by default then how?

And also blocks 
sales/order_email_items_order_grouped
and this
sales/order_email_items_order_default
where I could find them and what is their use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block `blocks sales/order_email_items_order_grouped` you can find it from

`app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\Grouped.php` and the block

`sales/order_email_items_order_default` you can find it from

`app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\Default.php` both block provides the valid methods for

`app\design\frontend\YOUR_VENDOR\YOUR_THEME\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml`

For example in this `default.phtml` you an find the         `<?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>` and the implementation of this method is in `Default.php`